# C# ?? operator with DBNull (Coalesce-like result)

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, ternary-operator

I'm getting DBNull results from DB.

Trying to apply ?? operator to it like

```
result["field1"] ?? result["field2"]
```

field1 = DBNull

field2 = 4

but it doesn't work, returns {} because result["field1"] is not null (it's DBNull). I expect to get that 4 from it.

Tried to do

```
result["field1"] = null
```

first, but it doesn't work, it's still DBNull type.

The question is how to handle this, convert DBNull to null in some way?
How to make ?? operator work with DBNull values?

---

To be more precise:

Is there a way to get **COALESCE**-like behaviour?

That 2 fields are just for example, in reality there will be much more fields and I'm trying to get first not null (so I was hoping to use chaining field1 ?? field2 ?? field3...)

I wasn't precise with that, sorry, my fault.

---

**SOLUTION**

Following Peter van der Heijden solution, say I'm getting from DB

result["field1"] = DBNull

result["field2"]= DBNull

result["field3"] = 4

```
result["field1"] ?? result["field2"] ?? result["field3"]
```

will return {} (first not null, DBNull is ... well ... not null)

but

```
result["field1"] as int? ?? result["field2"] as int? ?? result["field3"] as int?
```

will return result["field3"] = 4, as expected.

int? can be replaced with whatever result type you get (like DateTime? for example).

Comment: Is `result["field1"] == DBNull.Value ? result["field2"] : result["field1"]` an option?

Comment: use as `result["field1"] == DBNull.Value ? result["field2"] : 'result["field1"]`

Comment: If `result` is a `DataRow`, then you can use `IsNull` method. E.g. `result.IsNull("field1")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to do that as follows:

```
string s = result["field1"] as string;
```

or

```
int? i = result["field2"] as int?;
```

Or in your case:

```
string s = result["field1"] as string ?? result["field2"] as string;
```

Comment: THAT is a great idea - need to remember that! Also the best solution for the OP I guess...

Comment: Yes, it solves my problem. If result["field1"] = DBNull then result["field1"] == null is false BUT result["field1"] as int? == null is true. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the slightly longer variant:

```
result["field1"] is DBNull ? result["field2"] : result["field1"];
```

`??` does only work if the left operand is `null` and as `DBNull` is an instance of a class it is not `null`.

Side note @Amit:
The `is` operator does a type check. You can interpret it "as you read it": It checks if the type of `result["field1"]` is `DBNull`. See [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx). This should be faster then a value comparisson with `DBNull.Value`...

Comment: @AmitAgrawal Eh? That is C#.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal: Never heard of the `is` operator?

Comment: That's I am also asking `Why you using _is_`

Answer (score 1):

The `??` operator only works will actual `null` values, `DBNull` is just a type, and `DBNull.Value` is just a static value used to signify a null value from the database.

You can't get it to work with `??`, all you can do is manually check for `result["col"] != DBNull.Value`, but then obviously this can be put into a method or an extension method so it reads a little nicer.

The ternary operator is about as close as you are going to get: `var val = results["col"] != DBNull.Value ? (int)results["col"] : 0;`

Answer (score 1):

The `??` operator will never work with `DbNull.Value` since it is a instance of `DbNull`.

Use other checks for this, like:

```
result["field1"] != DbNull.Value ? result["field1"] : result["field2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DBNull.Value.Equals(result["field1"]) ? result["field2"]: result["field1"];
```